# Duplicate wait function but only 2 of them work as expected

Tags: apache-nifi

I have created 3 wait functions that waits for 87 files to be generated before it starts the processes in 3 other groups that I have created.

The wait works in 2 of the processes as expected but in the 3rd process it shows that in data provenance that it has received 86 signals but is still waiting for 1 more. Any idea why?

Wait Signal:

[image]

Data Provenance (missing one entry):
[image]

Data Provenance of duplicate Wait in another process that is working:
[image]